# Problems when interactively resizing and moving svg rectangles with D3

Tags: svg, d3.js, resize, panel, draggable

I am trying to create panel components that will hold some visualizations.
I am making the panel component with svgs. They look ok, but I am getting some weird behavior when resizing and moving the panels.

```
var groups = ["uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"];
var w = 350;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var width = 800;
var h = 200;
var height = 800;

var val = [];

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(Object)
    .on("drag", move);

var resize = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(Object)
    .on("drag", dragResize);

svg = d3.select("body").append("div").append("svg");
charts = svg.selectAll("g.chart")
           .data(groups); //(dims);
box = charts.enter()
    .append("g").classed("chart", true)
    .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "box"+i})
//.data([{x: 95, y: 0}]);


box.append("rect").classed("box", true)

var t = box.append("rect").classed("titleBox", true)
t.call(drag);
box.append("text").classed("title", true).data(groups)
box.append("text").classed("legend", true).data(groups)
box.append("rect").classed("icon", true)
    .call(resize);

box.selectAll("rect.box")
     .data([{x: 95, y: 0}])
     .attr({
           x: function(d) { return d.x; },
           y: function(d) { return d.y; },
           width: w,
           height: function(d) { return 200}//d.length*30 + 60}
      })

box.selectAll("rect.titleBox")
    .classed("drag", true)
    .data([{x: 95, y: 0}])
    .attr({
           x: function(d) { return d.x; },
           y: function(d) { return d.y; },
           width: w,
           height: 25,
           fill: "#000000"
     })


box.selectAll("text.title")
    .attr({
           x: 105,
           y: 20,
           width: 350,
           height: 25,
           fill: "#ffffff"
     })
    .text(function(d) {
           console.log("i from title "+ d);
             return d;
     })

box.selectAll("text.legend")
     .attr({
           x: 105,
           y: 45,
           width: 200,
           height: 25,
           fill: "#999999"
      })
      .text(function(d) {
           return d;
      })

box.selectAll("rect.icon")
    .data([{x: 429, y: 184}])
    .attr({
          x: function(d) { return d.x; },
          y: function(d) { return d.y; },
          width: 16,
          height: 16,
          fill: "#999999"
    })

var dx = 429;
var dy = 184;       

function move(){
     var dragTarget = d3.select(this);
     var dragObject = d3.select(this.parentNode);

     console.log("move x:"+x+" y:"+y);
     //console.log("d3.event.x:"+d3.event.x+" d3.event.y:"+d3.event.y);

     x += d3.event.x - parseInt(dragTarget.attr('x'));
     y += d3.event.y - parseInt(dragTarget.attr("y"));
     console.log("x:"+x+" y:"+y);

    dragObject
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
};

function dragResize(){
     var dragx = Math.max(dx + (16/2), Math.min(w, dx + width + d3.event.dx));
     var dragy = Math.max(dy + (16/2), Math.min(h, dy + height + d3.event.dy));

     //console.log("resize x:"+x+" y:"+y);
     console.log("d3.event.x:"+d3.event.dx+" d3.event.y:"+d3.event.dy);

     var dragTarget = d3.select(this);
     var dragObject = d3.select(this.parentNode);

     var o = dragObject.select("rect.box");
     var o1 = dragObject.select("rect.titleBox");


     var oldx = dx; 
     var oldy = dy;

    dx = Math.max(0, Math.min(dx + width - (16 / 2), d3.event.x)); 
    dy = Math.max(0, Math.min(dy + height - (16 ), d3.event.y));
    w = w - (oldx - dx);
    h = h - (oldy - dy);


    dragTarget
         .attr("x", function(d) { return dragx - (16/2) })
         .attr("y", function(d) { return dragy - (16) })

    o.attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", h);

    o1.attr("width", w);
};
```

I have posted the code at http://jsfiddle.net/dtqY5/

The problem is the following: I can move each panel, by dragging the title area, with no problem. Howvwer, after I resize any of the panels, I cannot move them anymore. They jump to their original position. The x and y becones NaN, but I cannot understand why.

ANy ideas and suggestions will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 uses the `drag.origin` accessor you provide to calculate an offset.  Since the access you provide is just an empty object, this offset is NaN which results in `x` and `y` on the event also being NaN.

If you remove `drag.origin` altogether it uses the current mouse position as the origin which makes the panels jump when you start dragging.  If you specify the origin to be the position of the shape being dragged it looks better:

```
.origin(function() {
    var current = d3.select(this);
    return {x: current.attr("x"), y: current.attr("y") };
})
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4nvhc/